# Hint on evaluating this integral

Tags: integration

I can't seem to come up with the proper integration technique to evaluate
$$
\int_0^1 t \cdot \sqrt{\frac{2}{2-t}} dt.
$$
I'd appreciate a push in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $2-t=u^2$ substitution. Then go through the steps.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that.  When I go to replace the limits, how do I know whether to take the positive or negative root?  E.g. when $t = 0$, $u^2 = 2$, so should $u = \sqrt{2}$ or $u = -\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: You are letting $u=\sqrt{2-t}$, so you want the positive roots.